# What is/was the two parameter constructor for RTCPeerConnection?

Tags: webrtc

The "official" WebRTC Samples show two parameters to RTCPeerConnection. For example:

```
pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, pcConstraints)
```

(From https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/audio/ )

This example works. However the latest documentation for RTCPeerConnection API shows only one parameter, a list of configurations options.

What was this two-parameter version, where is it documented, and why does the sample use it even though the document shows a different form? (And how does it still work!?)

Answer (score 2):

this was used to tweak some things like turning on ipv6 in chrome in the early days. It is long gone from the specification and should be removed from the samples as well.

It should be gone from the samples [soon](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/pull/992), thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Is it outdated again? Here's the latest doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/RTCPeerConnection I don't see a parameter for "servers".

Comment: that is just a variable name. The samples use "servers" in many places as the name for the configuration object.